# Schematic shows two outputs for Vout. Why?

Tags: schematics

How do I interpret the fact that Vout has two output points? My guess is that the two Vout points represent where I would place the probes on a multimeter. Is this correct?

See this diagram:

[image: Schematic showing AC voltage source, resistor, diode, ground and _two_ output terminals]

The article I'm reading suggests that there is only one signal for Vout, which looks like this:

[image: Output graph]

I'm really sorry for if this a basic question, I'm new.

Comment: "My guess is that the two Vout points represent where I would place the probes on a multimeter." I can only speculate why the drawer choose to show two output terminals, but yes this clearly indicates the nodes where you should place your voltmeter (multimeter). Usually ground or the lower rail designates ground (of the voltmeter probe)  and you may select the other node (probe) arbitrarily. Either the ground symbol or the lower terminal is redundant.

Comment: At first I thought why is the graph wrong, then I realize it's just theory that assume the diode forward voltage is 0V.

Comment: @try-catch-finally it's really common to see educational circuits drawn like this to give students a clear indication of where to put their probes. Most of the diagrams in my 1st yr notes have two output points as occasionally you measure across components rather than with respect to ground.

Comment: @JasonHan I learned about forward voltages in diodes yesterday! I'm pretty sure the article does state that for simplicity, forward voltage was omitted from the example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A voltage is relative between two points.  A voltage signal therefore always has two connections.

However, a circuit that has to deal with multiple signals usually wants them all referenced to the same point.  Since this comes up a lot, we call that point "ground".  We then often talk as if a signal is on a single line, implying that it's actually reference to ground.

Your diagram shows Vout between two points, because that's what it really is.  But also notice that the bottom Vout point is shown connected to ground.  In electrical engineering context, it would therefore be acceptable, and even common, to talk about Vout as if it were only on the top line.  When nothing special is said, the default is that ground is the reference for a signal.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I get it. It needs to be a circuit, it must return to ground.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, what exactly do you think is wrong?

Comment: @Olin, can you request to appropriate authorities to make it mandatory to give reasons for downvoting an answer?  Atleast till answer receives say 5 down votes?

Comment: At least try to motivate your downvote. I can't see anything remotely wrong with this answer.

Comment: Olin's answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: Olin's answer is perfectly fine. The only extra point I would add is that the input voltage is AC 10v p-p and this means, relative to ground, the vout will swing between +5v and -5v at a particular (unknown) frequency. It is common when starting to think of ground as the -ve but in fact it is the common relative 0v of the circuit and this is what the output graph is showing. The measured vout (y axis) with respect to 0v (X axis). The diode only conducts in one direction and therefore "removes" any 0v to +5v from the vout measurement.

Answer (score 3):

Voltage is always relative to a defined point. Notice that the bottom line connects to ground. So Vout is just the top line.

Comment: Now that makes sense, but then why does the diagram have the second Vout point?

Comment: @Mark Wears Glasses: "relative to" means that you must have a reference point. If there was only one Vout point given (and no line marked as GND), it would not be clear **between** which **two** points the voltage is measured.

Answer (score 0):

An output voltage is relative between two points

the high point which is the value of the output voltage

- the reference voltage 
  hear is the ground

in many case it is the ground like the car electronic system

but in other case it may be a negative point

Answer (score 0):

That's because the diagram is showing that your circuit is a half-wave rectifying circuit with a bias to ground effectively chopping off the positive peaks of the signal leaving the pulsed negative troughs.

A signal is an oscillating wave equidistant from 0 up to say 5 for example back down through zero down to -5 and back to zero.

Electricity in the US does this 60 times per second which is also known as Hertz.

An AC voltage signal however can't be measured or used with only one lead. If you want to use an oscilloscope to view your signal you must connect both the positive/hot and negative/ground/neutral leads. Without both, a return path isn't present for the sine-wave signal to complete the circuit. Your signal becomes useless and no voltage flows or can be measured.

Comment: 1.  Current flows, not voltage. 2. It takes two connections to measure voltage, regardless of AC or DC.